# How to specify the dimensions of a docusign templateTab

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to programmatically add tabs to a template using the [endpoint](https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=Templates&tags=TemplateTabs&operations=create) 
`POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/templates/{templateId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs`

I can reliably place `checkboxTabs`, `dateSignedTabs`, `signHereTabs`, and `initialHereTabs` but when it comes to placing `textTabs` (the most important ones) I can't seem to control the dimensions while using the [API Explorer](https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=Templates&tags=TemplateTabs&operations=create).

I enter Height and Width parameters

[image: height 11] [image: width 456]

But the request becomes

```
{
  "textTabs": [
    {
      "documentId": "1",
      "locked": "true",
      "pageNumber": "1",
      "required": "false",
      "tabLabel": "dataLabel",
      "xPosition": "200",
      "yPosition": "200"
    }
  ]
}
```

With a response like

```
{
    "textTabs": [
        {
            "isPaymentAmount": "false",
            "shared": "false",
            "requireInitialOnSharedChange": "false",
            "requireAll": "false",
            "required": "false",
            "locked": "true",
            "concealValueOnDocument": "false",
            "disableAutoSize": "false",
            "tabLabel": "dataLabel",
            "font": "arial",
            "bold": "false",
            "italic": "false",
            "underline": "false",
            "fontColor": "black",
            "fontSize": "size7",
            "documentId": "1",
            "recipientId": "XXXXXX",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "200",
            "yPosition": "200",
            "tabId": "e940cc97-a68c-4da6-9ffe-487439579bc6"
        }
    ]
}
```

and renders on the page as just a very small textbox.

[image: smallest textbox immaginable]

1) Is this a limitation of the [API Explorer](https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=Templates&tags=TemplateTabs&operations=create)?

2) Or are height and width not valid options when creating tabs from this endpoint? 
2.a) and if so, what's the proper way?

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely an issue with the api explorer: if you take the query it gives you and manually submit it with the desired parameters:

```
{
  "textTabs": [
    {
      "documentId": "1",
      "locked": "true",
      "pageNumber": "1",
      "required": "false",
      "tabLabel": "dataLabel",
            "height": "11",
            "width": "400",
      "xPosition": "200",
      "yPosition": "200"
    }
  ]
}
```

you will be able to set the `height` & `width`!

[image: a textBox with height and width]

Now Docusign might change them for reasons your human mind cannot comprehend. `400 !== 396 in the response` but don't worry, that's hopefully just part of the process. And count yourself lucky, at least that page of the API Explorer works, [unlike some endpoints](https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=Templates&tags=TemplateTabs&operations=list) which straight up [don't have documentation!](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/TemplateTabs/list/)

also, an example implementation of this using the [python sdk](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-python-client): (in case reading the [autogenerated code](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-python-client/blob/master/docusign_esign/apis/templates_api.py) isn't clear)

```py
tabs = {
    "checkboxTabs": [
        {
            "documentId": "1",
            "locked": "true",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "tabLabel": "check1",
            "xPosition": "100",
            "yPosition": "100"
        }
    ],
    "dateSignedTabs": [
        {
            "documentId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "300",
            "yPosition": "100"
        }
    ],
    "signHereTabs": [
        {
            "documentId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "200",
            "yPosition": "200"
        }
    ],
    "initialHereTabs": [
        {
            "documentId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "300",
            "yPosition": "200"
        }
    ],
    "textTabs": [
        {
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "50",
            "yPosition": "50",
            "tabLabel": "text1",
            "locked": "true",
            "required": "false",
            "documentId": "1",
            "height": "11",
            "width": "400"
        }
    ]
}
response = Template.template_api.create_tabs(recipient_id=recipient_id, template_id=template_id, account_id=Template.accountID, template_tabs=tabs).to_dict()
```